# css: vertical align text in the middle

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align some text vertically to the middle ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PzUZ4/))

I have spans with text only and spans which have a height set (inline-block elements)

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <span class="text">Bar</span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="text">Foo</span>  
</div>
```

The css:

```
.bar {
    display: inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

I need to have the text nicely align vertically to the middle of its parent. I tried to put `vertical-align: middle` on `.text` but for some reason only the values `top` and `bottom` seem to work. Any suggestions ?

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/PzUZ4/2/ You need to set `vertical-align:middle` to both the `.text` and the `.bar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
.parent {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.bar {
    display: inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.text {
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jayeshgoyani/PzUZ4/4/)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
.bar {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PzUZ4/)